# Writing data to firebase deletes node and no data is written

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have node structure like this:
[image: Firebase structure]

I want to edit or set nickname, because sometimes there will be no nickname.
When i execute this function it deletes all user node.
This is what i try to execute:

```
writeDataToFirebase() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/')
      .set({ nickname: this.state.nickname });
  }
```

What I am doing here wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to `update` rather than `set`?

Comment: @Emilis I dont think the '/' following the uid is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` method overrides the data you must use update methode to `update` or add data.
Check firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

```
firebase.database().ref().update({ 'nickname': this.state.nickname });
```

Comment: If i try to use update i get error Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.HahMap com.facebook.react.bridhe.ReadableMap.toHashMap()' on a null object reference

Comment: i forgot to add ' to nickname check the answer now